# Should I use jest.fn() for all mocked functions, even when it's not used?

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I can create a mock function either with `jest.fn(() => 1)` or with `() => 1`. Should I do the first even when I don't need it? (eg I'm not using `expect().toHaveBeenCalled()`)

```
const foo = ({ helper }) => helper()

test('example v1', () => {
  const arg = { 
    helper: jest.fn(() => 1) 
  }
  expect(foo(arg)).toBe(1)
})

test('example v2', () => {
  const arg = { 
    helper: () => 1
  }
  expect(foo(arg)).toBe(1)
})
```

Possible benefits of always using `jest.fn()` include:

- documentation—knowing it's supposed to be a mock function
- easy to add `expect(arg.helper).toHaveBeenCalled*()` later

Comment: Did you end up deciding on a preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock `helper` function once in only one unit test or always mock it in all unit tests, and you can restore the original implementation of `helper` function as well.

When you test `foo` function, mocked all functions it depends on so that you can make isolate environment for testing. No need to worry about the real return values from other functions and dependencies. Because we mocked return values for all dependencies.

update:

For simple code, it's ok. But, for complex code which means there are many conditions and statement branches, you need be should that the functions inside the function you want to test to be called indeed with correct parameters.

And, what if the function that accesses a database or sends an HTTP request. This case, you really need to make a test stub for it rather than access the real external resource. As I said, make an isolate sandbox environment for the unit test.

Comment: Updated question for clarity